# MFRC522 PICC responded with NAK (Porting MFRC522 arduino library[C++] to [C])

Tags: c++, c, arduino

**First some introducing.**

I am trying to make the [MFRC522 library](https://github.com/miguelbalboa/rfid) for Arduino work on an ATmega328 programmed in C(I am using a 'normal' controller first, to make it work on a raspberry pi in a later state).

I copied the .h and .cpp from the library to my own project and renamed the .c to .cpp. After removing the classes in the .h file, it was time for the .c file. I replaced all the 'byte' statements to 'uint8_t', replaced the 'Serial.print' with printf and did the changes for GPIO and SPI.

**The problem.**
After some small mistakes I finally got data from a keycard. However it looked like to work, I get an error with reading line 58 from the card. The error is:

> MIFARE_READ() failed: A MIFARE PICC responded with NAK.

I added a print statement to the SPI write and read and found out the following difference(on the left the [C] version and on the right the Arduino version): (because of my reputation, the picture can be found in the BitBucket I mentioned at the code part)

**Code**
The code is pretty long, but i made it [available on BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/SanderHuisman/nfc/src)

I hope someone can point me where to look(some [C++] >> [C] different interpretations), because I don't know anymore where to look.

Sander

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the PCD_Authenticate function before reads and writes. There are a few pre programmed keys in the linked github library that will authenticate the cards. I was getting this when trying to write to the card because I was using KEY_B and not KEY_A. You can see this Authenticate used in the samples provided on that GitHub page. It should looks something like this.

```
status = (MFRC522::StatusCode) mfrc522.PCD_Authenticate(MFRC522::PICC_CMD_MF_AUTH_KEY_A, trailerBlock, &key, &(mfrc522.uid));
```

From what I can tell the NAK simply means that the wrong key was used or maybe no key.